# pass URL in SMS body in android

Tags: android, sms

I am putting some predefined text in sms body and proceeding for SMS with below code

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri
                            .parse("smsto:" + unsuccessContacts));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Pssst, we are organizing an event in XYZ city. you can join us on http://example.com/invite.html. you gonna love this!");
startActivityForResult(smsIntent, SEND_SMS);
```

**so when it opens my SMS window it shows predefined text as**

"Pssst, we are organizing an event in XYZ city. you can join us on http://example.com/invite.html. you gonna love this!"

**but what i want is**

"Pssst, we are organizing an event in XYZ city. you can join us on http://example.com/invite.html. you gonna love this!"

**so basically i want a hyperlink** at "http://example.com/invite.html"

Can any one help me out with this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Some phones will automatically turn anything that looks like a URL into a link but there isn't a standard markup for putting a URL in an SMS

Comment: @Jared is correct. How an SMS message is rendered is completely up to the app displaying it. Your app, as sender, has no control over this.

Comment: That has to be possible as we can see some service providers messages with link in message body

Comment: So there has to be any way

Comment: You're misunderstanding what's happening, in that case. I've written several SMS apps that receive and display incoming messages, and there is no requirement that my apps display a given message as anything other than plain text (if even that). True, many, if not most, Android apps _will_ display URLs, phone numbers, etc. as links, if they are found in the message text, but there is nothing that demands they do so, and there's certainly nothing in the SMS protocol that can "force" text to be displayed in a certain manner in an arbitrary SMS app.

Comment: The best you can do is format your link exactly as you have it in your post (i.e., "http://..."), and hope that whichever app your recipient is using is smart enough to parse that and render it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Use in this manner

```
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri
                            .parse("smsto:" + unsuccessContacts));
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","Pssst, we are organizing an event in XYZ city. you can join us on http://example.com/invite.html. you gonna love this!"));
startActivityForResult(smsIntent, SEND_SMS);
```

or

```
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String text = "Pssst, we are organizing an event in XYZ city. you can join us on http://example.com/invite.html. you gonna love this!";
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, text, null, null);
```

Automatically android detect links and hyperlink it by default.

Comment: Have you tried this? I would be surprised if it worked

Comment: No it is not working. it shows SMS window with text "Pssst, we are organizing an event in XYZ city. you can join us on <a href='http://example.com/invite.html'>http://example.com/invite.html</a>. you gonna love this!"

Comment: is it fine if the sms is send in background without opening in the intent?

Comment: I have not checked in that manner but as per my requirement i have to send SMS through default native SMS app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71146/discussion-between-jigar-and-fahim).